# What is significance of node name in cq

Tags: aem, sling

I've seen that Node name of edit config in cq must be cq:editConfig.(apart from it's primary type being cq:editConfig).
From what i've inferred in cq so far, node is not that important cq as much as it's primary type. then, why name of the node cq:editConfig must be this, if it already has it's primary type as cq:editConfig.

any code regarding this(may be in sling API) will be much helpful.

Comment: You won't find this in Sling as the namespace implies this is a CQ specific one. And the CQ code isn't publicly available, so probably only an Adobe employee can answer that. I only know of Bertrand Delacretaz who is rather active here when you look at the top users of these tags.